# No route matches, missing required keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently working on rails 5 project in which I want to add a passenger to a transportation. In the in the passengers controller index action I set transportation to be search by the params id. But it returns nil even though it has been created.

[image]

Here are the routes:

```
user_protest_transportation_passengers GET    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers(.:format)          passengers#index
                                           POST   /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers(.:format)          passengers#create
 new_user_protest_transportation_passenger GET    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/new(.:format)      passengers#new
edit_user_protest_transportation_passenger GET    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/:id/edit(.:format) passengers#edit
     user_protest_transportation_passenger GET    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/:id(.:format)      passengers#show
                                           PATCH  /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/:id(.:format)      passengers#update
                                           PUT    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/:id(.:format)      passengers#update
                                           DELETE /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations/:transportation_id/passengers/:id(.:format)      passengers#destroy
              user_protest_transportations GET    /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations(.:format)                                        transportations#index
                                           POST   /users/:user_id/protests/:protest_id/transportations(.:format)
```

Here is the link:

```
<div class="card">
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Need A Ride?</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Find people near you willing to share a seat who are coming to the event. We are all in this together!.</p>
                    <%= link_to 'Get A Ride', new_user_protest_transportation_passenger_path(@user, @protest, @transportation), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the passengers controller:

```
class PassengersController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @transportation = Transportation.find(params[:transportation_id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @passenger = Passenger.new(passenger_params)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @transportation = Transportation.find(params[:transportation_id])
    @driver = User.find(@transportation.transporter_id)
    @protest = Protest.find(@transportation.destination_id)
    @transportations = Transportation.where(destination_id: @protest.id)
    has_ride = false

    @transportations.each do |transportation|
      passenger = Passenger.find_by user_id: current_user.id
      unless (passenger.nil?)
        has_ride = true
      end
    end

    if has_ride
      redirect_to protests_path, notice: "You already have a ride."
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @passenger.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_protest_transportation_passenger_path(id: @passenger.id), notice: 'Passenger was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @driver = get_driver
    if @driver
      @transportation = Transportation.where(transporter_id: @driver.id).first!
      @protest = Protest.find(@transportation.destination_id)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
    @passenger = Passenger.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], transportation_id: params[:transportation_id])
    if @passenger
      @passenger.destroy
      redirect_to user_protests_path, notice: 'Ride was canceled.'
    else
      redirect_to user_protest_transportations_path, notice: 'Error: the passenger record failed to delete.'
    end
  end

  private

  def get_driver
      driver = nil
      p = Passenger.find_by(user_id: current_user.id, transportation_id: params[:transportation_id])
      t = Transportation.find(params[:transportation_id])
      driver = User.find(t.transporter_id)
  end

  def passenger_params
    params.permit(:user_id, :transportation_id)
  end

end
```

I am trying to get the transportation id in the params, I tried find with `session[transportation_id]` but didn't seem to work.

protest controller:

```
class ProtestsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @protests = Protest.all
  end

  def show
    @protest = Protest.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
  end

  def new
    @protest = Protest.new
  end

  def edit
    @protest = Protest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @protest = Protest.new(protest_params)
    @protest.creator = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @protest.save
        format.html { redirect_to @protest, notice: 'Protest was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @protest = Protest.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @protest.update(protest_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @protest, notice: 'Protest was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html {render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @protest = Protest.find(params[:id])
    @protest.destroy

    redirect_to protests_path
  end

  private

  def protest_params
    params.require(:protest).permit(:name, :description, :location, :starts_at, :creator, :image)
  end

end
```

Comment: In this protests#show page, is your `@transportation` nil? Can you inspect that and also share the code of that action?

Comment: @kiddorails I have updated the question sharing the protest#show action. I think because I didn't declare transportation in the show action is giving me that error

Comment: yes. since `@transportation` is not present, the path helper can't find the transportation to substitute with `:transportation_id`. You should add related `@transportation` in `protests#show` and it should work